# Can I check who created the CFT stack in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Can I check who created the CFT stack in AWS?
is there a way to check who created the stack without using cloud trail?

Answer (score 1):

Add a tag or some output when the stack is made.

If you don't want to do this then Cloud Trail is the only other way